# Access to w.location.href in popup window, in background page, in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In background page:

```
var w = window.open(URL,'Example','width=675,height=350');
temp.page=setInterval(function(){
  if (w.location.href!=URL) {
    clearInterval(temp.page);
    alert(w.location.href); //undefined
    w.close();
  }
},1000);
```

So, why `w.location.href` is undefined and why I can't access to do any scripts in w (`w.document.write('qweqwe');//document==undefined`)?

I need to:
 1. Open page with URL.
 2. Detect redirect.
 3. Get URL whereto page have redirected me.
 4. Do something with the second URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added domain name of site in permissions, in manifest, and now I'm able to make AJAX requests to this domain.

Also permission "tabs" was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are running up against one of the primary security restrictions that are built-in to modern web browsers. What you are trying to do is called "cross-site scripting", and the simple answer is you are not allowed to do this.

Look up "cross-site scripting (XSS)" and "javascript code signing" for more information. Good luck!

Comment: I know about XSS. ;) By extension's permissions I can do ajax queries, e.g. on http://example.com. I think, for popup windows chrome extension's API has smth.